# Inserting NULL value to column of JSON type by multiple row insert query

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
rows = [{"id": 1, "json_value": [{"key": "value"}, {"key2": "value2"}]}, {"id": 2, "json_column": None}] 
insert_query = table.insert().values(rows)
connection.execute(insert_query)
```

Doing this will have "null" (String) entered to the row where id=2. Rather than the NULL type.

Is there any way to properly do multiple row insert where value of some JSON columns is NULL?

Comment: Sounds like SQLAlchemy's doing something wrong there. `None` should correspond to json `null` not `"null"` and thus to SQL `NULL`.

Comment: It also seems so to me. Just trying to find out if there is any other solution than adding an issue to the SQLAlchemy BitBucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a bug and has been fixed by the SQLAlchemy project maintainer.

Details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/Bu4lJ18Gsa8